# Issue making getEnvelope Rest API call, using JWT Authentication, returning "Invalid account specified for user"

Tags: .net-core, docusignapi

I have been working with JWT Authentication lately and recently have gotten it working with my application. I am able to successfully generate an auth token and can use said tokens in successful requests. One request I am having trouble with however is the getEnvelope call

```
var url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/" + **accountID** + "/envelopes/" + **envelopeID**;

            var client = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer **TOKEN_VALUE_HERE**");

            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<DocusignEnvelopeDataResponse>(request);

            DocusignEnvelopeDataResponse data = response.Data;
```

I have worked with this same integrator key and account previously, but now I keep getting this  response.

```
{"errorCode":"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. Invalid account specified for user."}
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with my Get request, or have any experience with issues like this in the past? When I am passing in account and envelope ids, I can confirm that the envelope id I am passing in is valid and does exist in said account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thought - are you using developer sandbox(demo) and/or production? can't mix accounts, IKs etc. between the two environments. Check your URLs, both the one used for auth, as well as the ones you use to make API calls.

Second thought, when you request a JWT token, you specify, among other things, the userID (GUID) for the user you will be impersonating.
Is it possible your token was generated using a userID that belongs to a different account?
The user must have access to the account.

Comment: I am using a developer sandbox demo account. I created the integrator key under that account, am using the "https://account-d.docusign.com/" base path when making the call for the oAuth token. In the code above I am using the demo base path "https://demo.docusign.net" for my call so that shouldn't be an issue. When requesting the JWT token I am using the same userID that I am using in the getEnvelope request so that should not be an issue either. Unless I am misunderstanding something

Comment: how is your IK configured in DocuSign admin? did you add an RSA keypair?

Comment: Yes, I had to use the Secret Key in the pair to generate the JWT object

Comment: maybe you confuse accountID and userID? you found 2 different GUIDs?

Comment: I used the integrator key (clientID) and API username (ImpersonatedUserGuid) in the initial JWT request, and I am using the same API username in the getEnvelopes call as the accountID, along with an envelope ID that is valid and can be accessed from said account on the docusign site

Comment: these are 2 different things. AccountID and userID. You need in the URL the AccountID and in the JWT token request - the userID. You can find them both in the same page in DocuSign admin for APIs and keys page. There are 2 GUIDs at the top, one for the account, one for your user. Hope that I'm explaining myself clearly.

Comment: Okay interesting I did not know that. In the admin page, where I can see the userID guid, I cannot see any other guids that I would believe to be an AccountID. I can see an account# on the far left side, but it is not a guid and I believe is tied to the account I am an admin of. Can you clarify any further on where and AccountID guid would be located?

Comment: Looking through the documentation at https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/get it looks like I can use the Account# int as well?

Comment: in the URL - always

Comment: the guid in the url seems to be the same as the guid in the API Username (the one that was used as the userID)

Comment: "seems to be the same" you mean in your code, how you did it. It's not supposed to be. I'm saying that's your issue. Did you try to change it?

Comment: Sorry, I was misunderstanding you. I though my the last "in the URL" comment you meant that the Account Guid was in the url of the docusign admin page when I was looking at a given user and seeing their UserID guid. Putting the Account# int in my request did solve my problem, thank you!